# C# WPF Binding to variable and property in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I got an integer in my viewmodel and a string in my view that I need to show combined.

This is the code in the view:

```
Binding buttonBinding = new Binding() {
        Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(ButtonViewModel.MyInteger)),
      };
      _button.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, buttonBinding);
```

Can I attach my string at some point or do I need to transfer it into the viewmodel and make the property a single string?

Comment: You can use a Converter and pass your string as parameter.

Comment: Where and how is the string defined?

Comment: @mm8 the String is defined in another class as public only accessible by the view (Its defined there for multilingual stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `ContentStringFormat` property to specify a `StringFormat` for the binding:

```
string s = "some string...";

Binding buttonBinding = new Binding()
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(ButtonViewModel.MyInteger)),
};
_button.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, buttonBinding);
_button.ContentStringFormat = $"{{0}} {s}";
```